# AdMob Ad not displaying and crashing ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, admob, xcode7

i am trying to display a native express ad on a view controller, but when i navigate to that view controller the app crashes with an uncaught exception. The ad unit id is also correctly taken from ad mob, and the ads is a 400 by 400 UIview.

```
 import UIKit

 import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADNativeExpressAdViewDelegate, GADVideoControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var ads: GADNativeExpressAdView!

 let adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-1330625274650885/2836069451"

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ads.adUnitID = adUnitId
  ads.rootViewController = self
  ads.delegate = self


    let videoOptions = GADVideoOptions()
    videoOptions.startMuted = true
   ads.setAdOptions([videoOptions])


 ads.videoController.delegate = self

    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]

    ads.loadRequest(request) }

func nativeExpressAdViewDidReceiveAd(_ nativeExpressAdView: GADNativeExpressAdView) {
    if nativeExpressAdView.videoController.hasVideoContent() {
        print("Received an ad with a video asset.")
    } else {
        print("Received an ad without a video asset.")
    }
}

func videoControllerDidEndVideoPlayback(_ videoController: GADVideoController) {
    print("The video asset has completed playback.")
}}
```

the log:

```
 2017-05-16 12:34:26.422: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS 
token Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "REMOTE_NOTIFICATION_SIMULATOR_NOT_SUPPORTED_NSERROR_DESCRIPTION" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=REMOTE_NOTIFICATION_SIMULATOR_NOT_SUPPORTED_NSERROR_DESCRIPTION}
2017-05-16 12:34:27.709 app[7285:3331371] -[UIView setAdUnitID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc4ec8a36d0
2017-05-16 12:34:27.732 app[7285:3331371] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setAdUnitID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc4ec8a36d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010be63d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010df52deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010be6cd3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bdb2cfa ___forwarding___ + 970
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bdb28a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   app                      0x00000001096c27ba _TFC14app14ViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 442
6   app                      0x00000001096c2af2 _TToFC14app14ViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 34
7   UIKit                               0x000000010cb37984 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
8   UIKit                               0x000000010cb3d93b -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 120
9   UIKit                               0x000000010cb6d750 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1203
10  UIKit                               0x000000010cb7db9b -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 712
11  UIKit                               0x000000010cb7ed0b -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
12  UIKit                               0x000000010cd2d503 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248
13  UIKit                               0x000000010ca57980 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c785c00 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c77a08e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c779f0c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c76e3c9 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c79c086 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
19  UIKit                               0x000000010c99772e _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7135
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd89301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd7f22c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd7e6e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd7e0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
24  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010fdf1ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
25  UIKit                               0x000000010c99cf09 UIApplicationMain + 171
26  app                      0x00000001096b10e2 main + 114
27  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ea1d92d start + 1
)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: upload your logs as well

Comment: @AmodGokhale Updated

Comment: -[UIView setAdUnitID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc4ec8a36d0 .. check your storyboard attributes for Ad IBOutlet is not set correctly